# What is the purpose of the below command?

Tags: linux, console, command

What is the purpose of the below command ?

```
grep -ir nashorn ./ | grep "^[^:]*\.java"
```

Answer (score 1):

If finds all lines that contain the string `nashorn`, case-insensitively, in files in the current directory hierarchy whose names contain `.java`.

The `-i` option to `grep` makes it match case-insensitively. The `-r` option makes it recurse into all directories in the directory arguments and search all the files. So the first part of the pipeline matches `nashorn` in all files in the current directory, recursively.

The output of that command will be in the format:

```
filename:matching line
```

The second `grep` matches those lines. `^` means the beginning of the lines, `[^:]*` means a sequence of characters that doesn't include `:`, which restricts it to the filename part of the line. ANd `\.java` matches `.java` literally. So it only matches lines where `.java` is in the filename part of the line.

Comment: Thanks for ur helping :)